# html5 attributes not working surface rt

Tags: html, internet-explorer, windows-rt

I have this tag `<textarea name="docBody" placeholder="main content" ></textarea>` included in a web page. The placeholder text shows correctly in Chrome on the desktop and my Nexus 7 as well as IE 11 on the desktop, but it doesn't work on my Surface RT with IE 11. I also noticed the same thing with a CSS animation. Is this something I'm doing wrong, or is it something about the Surface RT?

Comment: From what I've seen, IE is not too friendly to the `placeholder` attribute...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the website to your 'Compatibility View list'. Instructions can be found http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-au/support/web-browsing/browse-the-web-with-internet-explorer under the 'Browse the web>Notes' section.

Comment: It turns out that intranet sites were being added to the Compatibility View list by default, which was not a good thing in this case. Since the site was hosted locally, it was being added to the list and I just had to disable that setting.

Answer (score -1):

HTML5 is still in a working stage and not all browsers have developed the tools to see each attribute of HTML5. If it works on other surfaces and not on this one particular then I would assume that this is an issue specific to Surface RT.